# convert json object to json array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had received a json snippet, which has the following lines (string converted to json object)

```
"profile":{"id":"billg","name":"Bill Gates","countryCode":"US"}
```

now user adds one more profile, i need to convert profile object to an array of profile objects.

```
"profile":[{"id":"billg","name":"Bill Gates","countryCode":"US"},{"id":"steve","name":"Steve Jobs","countryCode":"US"}]
```

Any pointers or code is highly appreciated

Comment: Pointer #1) Try something first.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be really great if you show some code of yours: we basically don't know what's the source of this json string (JSON = JavaScript Object Notation, so 'JSON object' is a tautology), and we don't know how is the second profile created.

Consider this, though:

```
var jsonData = '{"profile":{"id":"billg","name":"Bill Gates","countryCode":"US"}}';
var data     = JSON.parse(jsonData); // it's an object now...
var profile  = data.profile;         // storing another object as a value of `.profile` property
var anotherProfile = {"id":"steve","name":"Steve Jobs","countryCode":"US"};
if (! profile[0]) { // checking whether it's an array or not
   // it's not, so we should make an array, adding another profile as well
   data.profile = [data.profile, anotherProfile]; 
}
else { // but if it was, it'd be enough just to push anotherProfile into the end of it
   data.profile.push(anotherProfile);
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This: 


   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('"profile":[{"id":"billg","name":"Bill Gates","countryCode":"US"},{"id":"steve","name":"Steve Jobs","countryCode":"US"}]');

    var a = obj.profile;

    var jsonArrObj = $.parseJSON('[' + a + ']');
```

You can access names in array like this :

```
for (i in jsonArrObj)
{
alert(jsonArrObj[i]["name"]);
}
```